# EXC_BAD_ACCESS variable exists but doesn't?

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access

I check for the variable's existence, but still get the exc_bad_access!  How is this possible?  I have tried Zombies, Instruments, and the console, to no avail, and about all else my limited knowledge can muster.  Any other suggestions??

```
if (intDealerCard) {
    NSLog(@"%i", intDealerCard);  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS - code 2 occurs here
}
```

Perhaps some things of note...
The code is being executed over 1000 times, as it is a simulation, and it will execute just fine numerous times.  I'd like to think there is a problem with my code, but the verified check throws me off.  Also, there are two different spots where this may happen, mostly in one of the spots, but occasionally in the other, but still, I'm not sure that is relevant seeing how the check is verified?!

Answer (score 2):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs when memory hasn't been managed properly.  Many times an app will crash with this error message in one place, however the memory management error has occurred elsewhere in the logic -- perhaps an unexpected dealloc is occurring on the instance of the class contains the member that is crashing, or if the app is running simulations concurrently, a race condition between a shared resource, etc.  In short, the few lines of code in your question are likely not the culprit, just a symptom of a more systemic error with how that variable's memory is being managed.

As you've run Zombies and nothing has shaken loose, consider running the static analyzer (Product > Analyze) -- this class of error can sometimes be detected via static analysis and present one or more code flows that could resulting early release, unexpected deallocation, etc.  These analysis errors and compiler warnings should be repaired and then you can retest using NSZombies if the error persists.

Comment: @BrettDoffing How unfortunate.  As indicated above, the few lines you've provided are likely not the problem, but an issue lurking elsewhere in that class or in the interplay between this class and a controller leveraging the capabilities of that class.  You'll need to spend time looking at how those interactions occur and look for scenarios where your code may not be managing memory the way you expect as the best the SO community will be able to do with those limited lines of code is offer generic debugging guidelines.  Refine your question, post more code, and we may be able to be more help!

Comment: Great explanation. The Analyzer gave me a few "Dead Store" messages, which I fixed, then ran with Zombies again, yet unfortunately nothing has changed.  About the only thing I am fairly certain of, and I could still be wrong, is that this variable, which I have now made a property to reduce allocations (and the problem still persists), is the culprit as the two log statements have been placed at the beginning of two different methods, whereby instead of the error occurring at various places in the method the property is accessed, it occurs at the beginning with the log statement.

Comment: I am trying to make it as simple as possible, and much thanks for any suggestions as I am hopefully only asking for general debugging guidelines.  With the info I have given so far, would you think this property could possibly not be the culprit?

Comment: @BrettDoffing it is impossible to tell from the information you've provided.  So maybe yes, maybe no :)

Comment: @Brian - I don't know if this is just a hack and my code should still be optimized in some way, or maybe I should have done this in the first place, but I simply used GCD at the start of each simulation and things seem to be working fine now!